# Is there any tax-deductible way to help fund my siblings' education?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, education-savings, education

My brother is in college and my sister is attending a private high school. I would like to help my parents pay for their education. Is there any way to do this that would be tax-deductible?

Answer (score 3):

You can contribute to a 529 plan for the benefit of your siblings.

([source](https://scs.fidelity.com/planning/college/content/fidelity_529_facts.shtml.cvsr))

Even better:  Show them how to [work around the system](http://lowestcostcolleges.com/).  (Not my website; not an affiliate link.)

Comment: You and the conspiracies again... Although I agree that you don't have to go to the most expensive college, being low-cost is not the only criteria to chose. If the cost is the problem - don't go to college at all. College education is not just a shiny plate from an on-line university, it's knowledge, and the quality of knowledge you get differs greatly from one college to another, that's why they're ranked even though all of them provide the "same" degrees.

Comment: +1 for low cost college link.  University charges have become much too high over the last two decades.

Comment: @littleadv:  Have you read the guide?  The content of your comment doesn't indicate that you have.

Comment: @mbhunter - yes, I went through it briefly. The main motive is "the government makes you pay this money but you don't have to". I consider the motive itself, which is very consistent in your answers as well, damaging and demeaning the rule of law. I have an advanced degree myself, and I paid through all my studies without taking a penny of debt, and I learned in a respectable institution in a respectable way. Maybe for the liberal arts (the ones that Dr. Gary is emphasizing on), it makes sense to do what he suggests. It's studies for fun anyway. For engineering - no.

Comment: I'll give it +1 for the guide. The guide has a lot of useful tricks -- even if you go the mostly conventional route but use one of the tactics to "quiz out" of a year of school, you've still saved $10-30K. It would be even better if it weren't written in the conspiracy nut tone. And this link would have been better written as a comment, since it is not really an answer to the question as asked.

Comment: I'll give it -1 for the incorrect answer. Contributions to a 529 are not **tax deductible**, which is what the OP was asking about.

Comment: Hmmm. I didn't read much of the guide, but I dug around on the site and he's got some fairly *unusual* opinions about how colleges offer courses. I only want to post a caution about using his advice, and nothing more than a cuation, as we are already heading down a threadjack. Caveat emptor.

Comment: @bstpierre With 529s, there may be a tax deduction for **state** income taxes.  See http://www.finaid.org/savings/state529deductions.phtml

Comment: @Chris - Thanks, I always forget about state deductions -- we don't have a regular state income tax.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is closer to a "no." 
The breaks are geared toward allowing a tax deduction for interest on student loans, not a deduction for the education cost itself.
@mbhunter's answer is great for the parents saving for a college education in the future, the growth in a 529 is tax free when used for higher education.

@tghw - you are kind to want to help. But it won't reduce your tax burden.

Comment: With 529s, there may be a tax deduction for **state** income taxes.  See http://www.finaid.org/savings/state529deductions.phtml

Comment: OP is in NY. There's a state deduction for 529, limit of $5000/single, but he might be able to benefit.

Comment: My NY relatives do exactly this.  They see it as a good way to stick it to one of the highest-taxed states in the country.

Comment: mbh - this is the one point that can make a 529 useful for the quick in/out, I'm unaware of other reasons to do so.